# Sending email to multiple recipients with html body

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, sharing, mailto

In my WinRT app I need to send email to multiple recipients with html body.
I have 2 Ideas (both don't works):

1. mailto: (doesn't work with html body [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body))
2. WinRT sharing  (can't set recipients directly)

My question: Is this possible to send one email to multiple recipients with html body in WinRT (c#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to send to multiple recipients with an HTML body.

- [mailto issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278363/emailing-to-multiple-recipients-with-html-mailto-not-working)
- [cannot set address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579040/is-it-possible-to-send-an-email-to-a-specific-recipient-through-share-contract)

Instead, you might want to consider using an email service to send the email on behalf of the end user (from a general account shared by your application users).